# Is aliasing of pointers between aggregate C structs and their members standards-compliant?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

Is the following a standards-compliant C program (and by which standard(s))? If it is non-compliant (by breaking the strict aliasing rule or otherwise) is it "safe" with respect to GCC or any other commonly-used C compiler?

```
int main()
{
    typedef struct {
       int data;
    } Type1;

    typedef struct {
       float data;
    } Type2;

    typedef struct {
       Type1 type1;
       Type2 type2;
    } Aggregate;

    Aggregate aggregate;
    aggregate.type1.data = 1;
    aggregate.type2.data = 2.0;

    Aggregate *p_aggegregate = &aggregate;
    Type1     *p_type1       = (Type1*) &aggregate;
    Type2     *p_type2       = (Type2*) &aggregate;

    int   data1 = p_type1->data;
    float data2 = p_type2->data;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p_type2` doesn't point to an object of type Type2, how do you propose to use that pointer? Or do you not intend to use it?

Comment: Merely pointing a pointer to an object doesn't access it. So aliasing isn't an issue.

Comment: `Type1     *p_type1       = &aggregate` and the `Type2` variant are an incompatible pointer conversion.

Comment: The strict aliasing rule (C11 6.5 §7) only matters when you actually start to re-reference the stored values of the objects. This code only contains various illegal pointer conversions, it has little to do with strict aliasing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - the code has been updated to cast pointers and dereference them.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Strictly spoken, your program is standard compliant (C11, C99, dunno about K&R).  It contains only pointer conversions and there are very little rules in the C standard which are restricting it</del>

Your

```
Type1     *p_type1       = &aggregate;
Type2     *p_type2       = &aggregate;
```

breaks type safety and probably every compiler will warn about it as an invalid type conversion.  <del>But it is covered by</del>

> 7 A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type.
>   [6.3.2.3 "Pointers", C11 draft]

<del>I have not found a rule which requires an explicit cast</del>

```
Type1     *p_type1       = (Type1 *)&aggregate;
```

<del>and paragraph above uses a similar wording like paragraph 1 one which  allows the commonly used implicit something to/from `void *` conversion.</del>

Access to both variables is valid because `&aggregate == &aggregate.type1`.

But as said, it is a really bad and unsafe style to write things in this manner and usual coding styles will consider this as an error. Access will be undefined when you add e.g. a `char foo;` attribute before `type1`.

EDIT:

Program is invalid; it violates

> — the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and [...] both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types [...]
>   [6.5.16.1 "Simple assignment"]

with

> 2 For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types. [6.7.6.1 "Pointer declarators"]

Comment: thanks; fixed the paragrah.  But the alignment can change.  C standard does not define how a structure is to be aligned. There can be architecture dependent ABIs which require that a structure is aligned like their most-aligned attribute.  But this is not required by C.

Comment: Some ABIs require this, but not C.

Comment: If the pointers are not pointing at compatible types, then an explicit cast is required to force the conversion. This is required by the rules for simple assignment 6.5.16.1. Qualifiers must also match. The relevant section "the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified pointer type, and (considering
the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;"